# How do I make a VM where none of the project editors can ssh into the machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

With the gcloud command anyone with editor level access to connect to any of the machines. While most machines we want to make accessible to anyone, some of the machines we don't want people touching. How can I set it up to where people editors can't ssh into certain machines?

Comment: Did you look into block-project-ssh-keys? See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#block-project-keys

Comment: That one still lets project owner ssh in through gcloud command. I don't know if it still lets other ssh in. Seems to me like this blocks the ssh keys added to the project level but not the editor level gcloud members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use some more fine grained roles than the primitive ones (which are owner, editor and viewer).

From the doc :

> If you just want to give a user the ability to connect to a virtual machine instance as an SSH user, but don't want to grant them the ability to manage your Compute Engine resources, add a user's public key to the project, or add a user's public key to a specific instance.

Here the whole [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/).